change pivot orientation by 3 reference points
I have this scene (2cubes with some random rotation but one of their corner is touch each other) :

By pressing CTRL + .   , I want to orient the pivot of these box ( does not matter which box), to match the orientation of the virtual plane which built by these 3 vertices ( A, B, C) :

So the new pivot will be at B and the Zaxis should perpendicular to this virtual ABC plane. How can I do this ?


Separate the ABC vertices into a different object and make a face with them.
Then just grab the object with Snapping active and set to face to orient it to the normal of the ABC triangle

Then change the snapping to vertices without rotation and move the origin to the original vertex and delete the triangle

